# Rambam seems to say that a craftsmen's Union may restrict competition. Is this in line with Chazal's thinking?

Tags: business

[Rambam Hilchos Mechirah 14 (10)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sales.14.10?lang=bi&with=Migdal%20Oz&lang2=en) states:

> Similarly, craftsmen in a specific profession may establish provisions
> and agree that one should not work on the day on which another is
> working or the like, and that anyone who violates these guidelines
> will be punished in such and such a fashion.

This seems to permit the craftsmen to restrict competition; as a result of onlt one craftsman being available on each day, the likelihood is that prices will be higher than otherwise.

I had always thought (without sources!) that Chazal's attitude to competition was that it is a good thing. Can the apparent conflict be resolved?

Comment: I think Chazal were in favor of competition because then nobody could make the prices too high. But if there's no issue of prices, then I guess there's no problem of unionizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for guilds and such are laid out in the first perek of Bava Basra. Unfettered competition can violate the rule of "Lo sasig" which forbids a person to encroach on his neighbor's livelihood. The exact limitations and whether this applies when the public will benefit is a matter of dispute.

Chazal only allowed unfettered competition in a few areas, the primary one nowadays being the teaching of Torah. Otherwise, they very delicately balanced the benefit of the public from competition with the benefit to the individual of a stable livelihood. See the first perek of Bava Basra at length.

As politely as possible, please allow me to say that an assumption without sources and a Rambam based on a Gemara do not really create a "conflict."

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the delicately worded last paragraph - quite right too!